# Export to excel using maatwebsite excel 2.0.8 and laravel 5.2 error - can't reach this page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I have this strange error in my system where exporting function using maatwebsite excel in my `public function exportSales()` works very successfully but when  `public function exportInventory` is called, it doesn't works. Below is my code for both functions.

**SaleController.php**

*this function works and downloads SalesReport.xls*

```
public function exportSales( $param = null ){

    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();

    $arrayMonths = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

    if( !$param ){

      Excel::create('SalesReport', function($excel){
      $excel->sheet('sales_sheet', function($sheet){
      $sales = Sale::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
      $sheet->loadView('sales/view_sales_excel', [ 'sales' => $sales ]);

      });

     })->download('xls');

    } else if( in_array( ucfirst( $param ), $arrayMonths ) ){

      Excel::create('SalesReport', function($excel) use($param){
      $excel->sheet('sales_sheet', function($sheet) use($param){
      $sales = Sale::orderBy('created_at','desc')
                         ->where('month', 'ILIKE', '%'.$param.'%')
                         ->get();
      $sheet->loadView('sales/view_sales_excel', [ 'sales' => $sales ]);

      });

     })->download('xls');                   

  }else{

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Cannot export with a parameter '.$param.'. Please contact developer for additional functions needed. Thank you.');

  }

}
```

**InventoryRecordController.php**

*this function doesn't work and returns can't reach this page error*

```
public function exportInventory( $param = null ){

    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();

    if( !$param ){

      Excel::create('InventoryReport', function($excel){

        $excel->sheet('inventory_sheet', function($sheet){

          $inventory = InventoryRecord::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
          $sheet->loadView('inventory/view_inventory_excel', [ 'inventory' => $inventory ]);

        });

      })->download('xls');

                          
    } else{

      /*$products = InventoryRecord::orderBy('pharmaceutical','asc')
                         ->where('type', 'ILIKE', '%'.$param.'%')
                         ->orwhere('unit', 'ILIKE', '%'.$param.'%')
                         ->get();*/
      return redirect()->back()->with( 'message', 'Cannot export with the parameter '.$param.'. Please contact developer for additional functions needed. Thank you.' );                   

    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

Here are some screenshots of my code editor:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please do note also that I am using xampp with 7.2.12 version, maybe this matter? Please help me figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: First you need to enable error reporting on both PHP and Laravel levels.
To enable on Laravel, set `APP_DEBUG` to `true` on `.env` file.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#configuration

Comment: already do that. thanks

Comment: If you do that you should see a detailed error trace on browser. Do you see that error page on other errors?